# Can´t start the server created from the express.js generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to setup a express.js server using there generator. I have followed the documation and I have succesfully created the basic structure. However if I try to run the given command (`SET DEBUG=transcriptverificationserver:* & npm start`) to start the server I always get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-28T22_43_43_285Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\a\Desktop\Verified Transcripts\Webpage> npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-28T22_45_41_209Z-debug-0.log
```

I assume its an issue within the package.json file. The script part looks as following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
```

I haven´t change anything in the files or structure and I was simply copying the commands from the documentation (https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html)
Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Are you sure that  this it the `package.json` inside `Webpage`?

Comment: @Konrad I have created the Webpage folder. The generator created another folder inside. If I open that folder I got the typical structure: bin, public, routes, views, app.js and package.json. I have opend this package.json file and copied to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried it again and this time everthing works. I am not sure what has happend before but I might have used the old installation method.

```
$ npm install -g express-generator
$ express
```

With my secound try I ensured to use the new method:

```
$ npx express-generator
```